# Replace Woocommerce Attribute name with an icon or an image

Tags: attributes, woocommerce

I'm using the Divi theme along with WC.
I have created 3 product attributes for my tea shop.
I wish to display an image on the front end rather that the name (or label) of the attribute.

For instance, instead of reading Steeping Temperature, I would like to display the image of a thermometer.

I am not a programmer / developper.
Please help
Steph

Answer (score 0):

it is posible to use 
after
in css for add an icon to each title of attributes.

```css
#attribute45896{
content:" ";
background-image:url('http://rapido.ir/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/blue.png');
background-size:30px;
background-position:left center;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
padding-left:40px}
```

```html
<table>
<tbody>
<tr class="alt">
<th id="attribute45896">color:</th>
<td><ul class="jcaa_attr_select jcaa_size_small jcaa_rounded_corners">
<li style="list-style:none;">red
</li>
</ul>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
<table>
```

but woocommerce do not set an auto id or random class to attributes.